# Applications of quadratic formula to finding roots

Tags: polynomials

I have been given the following question. I think I should be applying the quadratic formula to find the roots of each, but a bit unsure on how to apply it in parts b and c. How should I go about determining the 'b' value in question b, and how would we even start applying the quadratic fromula in part c?

Question 3: Find the roots of the following equations: $a) \quad y=2x^2+4x-3 \\ b) \quad y=-9x^2+3 \\ c) \quad y=(4x+2)^2$

Comment: Is this a Mathematica software question or a mathematics question? If the former, please add to your question the code you have tried and the difficulties you have encountered.  If the latter, it belongs in [math.se], where it may receive more relevant answers.

Answer (score 0):

In question $b$, the "$b$" coefficient, the coefficient for the $x^1$ term, is there, so to speak, it is just zero. $y=-9x^2+0x+3$: $a=-9,b=0,c=3$.

The formula gives:

$$x=\frac{-0\pm\sqrt{0^2-4\cdot(-9)\cdot3}}{-18}=\frac{\pm\sqrt{108}}{-18}=\pm\frac{6\sqrt{3}}{18}=\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$

For question $c$, you do not need the formula. When a quadratic is factored like this, it is easy to see that it is zero if and only if the brackets equal zero:

$$y=(4x+2)^2=0\iff 4x+2=0\implies 4x=-2\implies x=-\frac{1}{2}$$

And although there are two roots, the roots are *both* $-\frac{1}{2}$. This idea is called "[multiplicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicity_(mathematics)#Multiplicity_of_a_root_of_a_polynomial)".

You *could* have used the formula, it would have just taken longer:

$$y=(4x+2)^2\implies y=16x^2+16x+4$$

$$x=\frac{-16\pm\sqrt{16^2-4\cdot16\cdot4}}{2\cdot16}=\frac{-16\pm\sqrt{16\cdot16-16\cdot16}}{32}=\frac{-16\pm0}{32}=-\frac{1}{2}$$